# Google Drive Push Notifications - multiple hits for a single change event

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to set up Google Drive Push Notifications to monitor changes to a folder.

The code:

```
    $channel = new \Google_Service_Drive_Channel;
    $channel->setId('ZZZ');
    $channel->setResourceId('a1b2c3');
    $channel->setType('web_hook');
    $channel->setToken('superToken');
    $channel->setAddress('https://mydomain/notification');
    $folderId = '0BzNPrO3YVvJKU1J6NklYcThFMjQ';
    $res = $service->files->watch($folderId, $channel);
```

$res contains confirmation information and once I upload a file into that folder, I do get a notification hit ('sync' signal is also received fine).

Once I receive a change notification I echo '200' string, as it is recommended in Google Drive API reference:

```
To indicate success, you can return any of the following status codes: 200, 201, 202, 204, or 102.
If your service returns 500, 502, 503, or 504, the Drive API will retry with exponential backoff.
```

The problem is that I get multiple notifications for a single change event, and they do seem to arrive after a longer period of time every time (matches the "exponential backoff" behaviour). At the same time, **maxChangeIdCount** of Changes resource does not increment.

So it seems that Google Drive pusher does not see the successful 200 code and retries the notifications. Which, of course, presents a huge problem - it's very difficult to verify that the change has indeed taken place.

So, the questions are:

- what is the correct response to notification - is it a string "200" or HTTP response code 200 without response body
- how can I *guarantee* that there will always be only one notification update when a watched file changes.

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a misbehavior of google servers. I have the same problem using Drive v3 API. As workaround I just ignore the duplicates based on *pageToken* parameter of *resourceUri* header property.

Answer (score 2):

- what is the correct response to notification - is it a string "200" or HTTP response code 200 without response body

Its a 200 HTTP response code: the response can be with an empty body

- how can I guarantee that there will always be only one notification update when a watched file changes

There are 2 possible reasons why you are receiving duplicate notifications: You are not sending a 200 response code (and not returning a string 200 as the body) so Google guesses that you did not receive the notification and keeps send you the same . Or maybe you have more than 1 channels open at the same time. If that code is executed more than once in just an hour (or more depending the default expire time that google is setting) you are creating more than one channel and google is pushing the notifications to all of the open channels.

What you can do:

- You can ensure that you are sending a 200 http response code
- Depending on how your code is structured, if you can ensure that only 1 channel is open, than google only sends you 1 notification, that is, only create a new channel if the previous has expired

Comment: Sending a 200 back immediately did the trick. Thanks!